# As3 project with Preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader, flashdevelop

I want to use the Preloader provided by FlashDevelop but it does not react as it should.

My loader tells me 100% when no file has been downloaded.

The code should display a trace() containing the percent intermediary but does not

Could you help me?

Mains.as

```
package
{
   import flash.display.Loader;
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.net.URLRequest;

   [Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
   public class Main extends Sprite
   {
       public function Main():void
       {
           if (stage) init();
           else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
       }

       private function init(e:Event = null):void
       {
           removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
           // entry point
           var imgRequest:URLRequest         = new URLRequest("http://next-web.be/actionscript/0.jpg");
           var img:Loader = new Loader();
               img.load(imgRequest);
           addChild(img);
       }
   }
}
```

Preloader.as

```
package
{
   import flash.display.DisplayObject;
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.display.StageAlign;
   import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
   import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
   import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

   import flash.display.Sprite;

   public class Preloader extends MovieClip
   {
       private var bar:Sprite;

       public function Preloader()
       {
           if (stage) {
               stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
               stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
           }
           addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
           loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
           loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

           // TODO show loader
           bar = new Sprite();
           bar.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x4444ff, 1, true);
           bar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 6);
           bar.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - bar.width / 2;
           bar.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - bar.height / 2;
           addChild(bar);
       }

       private function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
       {
           trace(e.text);
       }

       private function progress(e:ProgressEvent):void
       {
           // TODO update loader
           bar.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0, 0);
           bar.graphics.beginFill(0x8888ff);
           bar.graphics.drawRect(1, 1, (e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal) * 98 , 4);
           bar.graphics.endFill();
           trace( "loading:" + (e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal) * 100 );
       }

       private function checkFrame(e:Event):void
       {
           if (currentFrame == totalFrames)
           {
               stop();
               loadingFinished();
           }
       }

       private function loadingFinished():void
       {
           removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
           loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
           loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

           // TODO hide loader
           removeChild(bar);
           bar = null;

           startup();
           //stop();
       }

       private function startup():void
       {
           var mainClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("Main") as Class;
           addChild(new mainClass() as DisplayObject);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask your questions in both english and french, also don't use saluations and sigs in your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your listener on the `contentLoaderInfo` property of the `Loader` you use to download the data (in your case `img.contentLoaderInfo`).

In your code, you register `progress` on `loaderInfo`, which is a field of your `Preloader` class (inherited from `MovieCLip`), and will give you the progress on loading the SWF that contains the `Preloader` class.

```
public class Preloader extends MovieClip
{
    public function Preloader()
    {
        // This is wrong.
        loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
        // Function `progress` will show the progress of loading your SWF file,
        // *not* the JPEG you're loading in class Main.
    }
}
```

You need to register your listener on the `contentLoaderInfo` property of the `Loader` you use to download the data (in your case `img.contentLoaderInfo`).

```
img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
```

Of course, then it will show *only* the progress of loading the JPEG file.
You'll also need to either pass the `Loader` object (or just the `contentLoaderLinfo`) to the `Preloader` somehow, or include the event handler in your `Main` class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I do not quite understand what you mean, my understanding of English could be better.

From what I understand, I simply add: `img.contentLoaderInfo;` in my file main.as But I'm not sure I applied it.
Here's what I did:


private function init(e:Event = null):void{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // entry point
    var imgRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://...");
    var img:Loader = new Loader();
    img.contentLoaderInfo;
    img.load(imgRequest);
    addChild(img);
}

Comment: I've edited the answer. Hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

After a continued search, I realized my mistake.

Until now, I always use "loader" but this function does not include my pictures to swf file. So I use a library swc allowing me to generate a complete swf.